# SQL - Combining 2 Table to get 1 table result

Tags: sql-server-2008

Let's say i have 2 have tables

Selling

```
ProductName    SellingDate    ProductID   
iPhone 4G      2011-05-11     1
iPhone 4S      2011-05-12     2
iPhone 4S      2011-05-13     2
iPhone 4G      2011-05-15     1
```

Buying

```
ProductName    BuyingDate    ProductID   
iPhone 4S      2011-05-09     2
iPhone 4G      2011-05-10     1
iPhone 4G      2011-05-13     1
iPhone 4G      2011-05-14     1
```

How to Combine This Date to be like this ?

```
ProductName    Date          Status      ProductID   
iPhone 4G      2011-05-10    Buying      1
iPhone 4G      2011-05-11    Selling     1
iPhone 4G      2011-05-13    Buying      1
iPhone 4G      2011-05-14    Buying      1
iPhone 4G      2011-05-15    Selling     1
```

I don't have any idea how to combine 2 tables date(SellingDate/BuyingDate) into 1 table (Date)...

Any help would be Appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your desired output **does not match** your given inputs so if this is just a case to combine both tables, a `UNION ALL` should be sufficient.

```
SELECT ProductName, Date, 'Buying' AS Status, ProductID FROM Buying
UNION ALL SELECT ProductName, Date, 'Selling' AS Status, ProductID FROM Selling
```

You can either use the following to add a user selectable productid

```
SELECT ProductName, Date, 'Buying' AS Status, ProductID FROM Buying WHERE ProductID = 1
UNION ALL SELECT ProductName, Date, 'Selling' AS Status, ProductID FROM Selling WHERE ProductID = 1
```

or this

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (
         SELECT ProductName, Date, 'Buying' AS Status, ProductID FROM Buying
         UNION ALL SELECT ProductName, Date, 'Selling' AS Status, ProductID FROM Selling
       ) p
WHERE   ProductID = 1
```

If you do need **those** outputs for given inputs, you will have to give us some additional information

1. What happened to ProductID 2?
2. What happened to the iPhone 4S series?
3. Why aren't these retained?

As a side note and for future reference, please be as excact and complete as possible. I assume that your downvotes are a result of your outputs not matching your inputs.

Comment: iPhone 4S series and Product ID 2  just an example that's show there is another product.. 
in my program i want to show the table according to the product the user choose..

Comment: @user1392096 - All you need to do then is add an appropriate where clause to the unions and you are good to go.

Comment: @user1392096 - two possible examples added.

Comment: how to put SellingDate and BuyingDate in one table?
what i mean is how we move this 2 Table entire data to a new table that in this case 'date'?

Comment: @user1392096 - `INSERT INTO date SELECT * FROM (...UNION ALL...)`